# How to extract Gist, Color Histogram and Zernike Vectors from an Image (MATLAB)

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, feature-detection

I'm doing some research in Content Based Image Retrieval (CBIR) and a certain part of it involves the extraction of three feature vectors- Color Histogram, Gist, and Zernike Moment.Firstly, i'm trying to implement the process followed in a research paper. The link is given below. Please jump to Section 3.2, "Each image is represented by 3 vetors..". I would be grateful if someone can give me a clue how to get started.

http://www.m-hikari.com/ams/ams-2014/ams-161-164-2014/souissiAMS161-164-2014.pdf

Now i have found various scripts on the internet which (perhaps) may do the job but being relatively new to the field of image processing and a beginner in MATLAB, i'm pretty much overwhelmed. I would really, really appreciate it if someone could explain to me in simple terms, how to exactly implement the process given in section 3.2 and extract the vectors.

I have also attached images which describe what was done. I would be grateful if someone could explain how this can be implemented in MATLAB.

[Color vector descripton](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gWWoU.png)

(Unfortunately, i cannot post more than one image, so kindly look at section 3.2 in the research paper for details about the gist and the zernike vector)

EDIT : Apologies if this sounded very vague and abstract. I have found three scripts for the job. The functions are as follows:

**function [gist, param] = LMgist(D, HOMEIMAGES, param, HOMEGIST)** /* for gist computation */

**Color Histogram Computation :**

**function H = rgbhist(I,nBins,Nind)**
RGBHIST: color Histogram of an RGB image.
nBins   : number of bins per EACH color => histogram is 'nBins^3' long.
Nind    : Normalization index

```
      0 -> Un-Normalized historam
      1 -> l1 normalized
      2 -> l2 normalized
```

H       : The vectorized histogram.

**Zernike Vector computation :**

**function [Z, A, Phi] = Zernikmoment(p,n,m)**

Function to find the Zernike moments for an N x N binary ROI

[Z, A, Phi] = Zernikmoment(p,n,m), where
 1. p = input image N x N matrix (N should be an even number)
 2. n = The order of Zernike moment (scalar)
 3. m = The repetition number o.f Zernike moment (scalar)
 4. Z = Complex Zernike moment 
 5. A = Amplitude of the moment
 6. Phi = phase (angle) of the moment (in degrees)

If someone could indicate how (if at all it is possible) to extract the given vectors using these functions, it would be great. Sorry for the long post. Thanks.

Comment: you should provide your solution as far as you get. this is not a free coding service. what exactly is your problem? I'm sure google will give plenty of examples of how to implement a color histogram in matlab.